# Android : How to change text color on only one menu item toolbar

Tags: android

I have the xml menu :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item

        android:id="@+id/nb_invalid"
        android:title="0"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nb_valid"
        android:title="0"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/validation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/validation"
        app:showAsAction="always" />



</menu>
```

I want change the color of the menu item text red for nb_invalid and green for nb_valid

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
     MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.nb_invalid);
     SpannableString s = new SpannableString("0");
     s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);
     item.setTitle(s);

     return true;
}
```

**I tried also but it doesn't work**

```
menu.findItem(R.id.nb_valid).setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff3824'>0</font>"));
```

My xml toolbar in my activity :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and my code:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initToolbar();

  }

 private void initToolbar() {

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 }
```

I work with api 25 ...

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean result = super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    styleMenuButton();
    return result;
}

private void styleMenuButton() {
    // Find the menu item you want to style
    View view = findViewById(R.id.YOUR_MENU_ITEM_ID_HERE);

    // Cast to a TextView instance if the menu item was found
    if (view != null && view instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) view).setTextColor( Color.BLUE ); // Make text colour blue
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

change you **oncreateOptionsMenu** Below like this

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    int positionOfMenuItem = 0; // or whatever...
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My red MenuItem");
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);
    item.setTitle(s);
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 findViewById return null;
Solution 2: doesn't work argument 2 inflater doesn't exit

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, **MenuInflater inflater)** check properly

Comment: I can't override this function I have one only parameter menu...?
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)